# My IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory implementation is causing StackOverflowException on IdentityServer4

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I built an identity server using IdentityServer4 with Asp.NET Core Identity on Asp.NET Core. I want to map my ApplicationUser's properties to the claims sent when a client accesses UserInfoEndpoint.

I tried to implement IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory as follows:

```
public class CustomUserClaimsPrincipalFactory : IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser>
{

    public async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> CreateAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        var principal = await CreateAsync(user);
        ((ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity).AddClaims(new[] {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, user.FirstName),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Surname, user.LastName),
    
         });
        return principal;
    }
}
```

and register it like:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
                .AddClaimsPrincipalFactory<CustomUserClaimsPrincipalFactory>();
```

but I am getting StackOverflowException when the client tries to access the UserInfoEndpoint.

Can you please help me fix this?

Note: I tested it and I don't get any errors when I don't register the ClaimsPrincipal factory.

Comment: `var principal = await CreateAsync(user);` you are calling the method recursively until the stack is full. You probably want to call something different here, some usermanager or the repository?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

isn't this line recursive, the function is calling itself recursively in an endless loop

```
var principal = await CreateAsync(user);
```

CreateUser is the function you are in and you call it again recursively which creates an infinite loop, hence stack overflow

Comment: Damn. I will format my computer, give up coding and become a fashion blogger.

Answer (score 4):

First, change the line

```
public class CustomUserClaimsPrincipalFactory : IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser>
```

to

```
public class CustomUserClaimsPrincipalFactory : UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser,IdentityRole>
```

then, change the line

```
var principal = await CreateAsync(user);
```

to

```
 var principal = await base.CreateAsync(user);
```

Comment: There is no `base` when simply implementing an interface.  This method will have to be fully defined by the developer.

Comment: You are right @MikeGuthrie.
The line 
public class CustomUserClaimsPrincipalFactory : IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser>

needs to be
public class CustomUserClaimsPrincipalFactory : UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser,IdentityRole>